# Swiftui / page frame

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The page I created is shifting to the left. I am getting a purple color error in the frame settings. "Invalid frame size (not negative or finite)." How can I fix? I'm learning Swiftui new I don't know what I did wrong.
[image]

[image]

```
  ZStack { 
  GeometryReader{ geometry in
                Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
  VStack {
      Text("Picture").font(.system(size: 60)).foregroundColor(.init(red: 45/255, green: 0/255, blue: 112/255))
                   
      TextField("Adınız", text: $Name.text)
           .foregroundColor(.white)
           .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
           .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
           .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
           .accentColor(Color.white)
          .frame(width: geometry.size.width - 100, height:50 , alignment: .center)
          .padding(5)
          .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
          .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:
          30).stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5411764706, green: 0.4549019608, 
          blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 1))
               
     TextField("Soyadınız", text: $profilSurname)
          .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
          .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
          .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
          .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
          .accentColor(Color.white)
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .frame(width:  geometry.size.width / 100, height:50 , alignment:.center)
          .padding(5)
          .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
          .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 
          30).stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5411764706, green: 0.4549019608, 
          blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 1))

           Text(iliski)//-------------->this
         .frame(height: 50)
         .foregroundColor(.white)
         .font(Font.system(size: 25, design: .default))
         .padding(5)
         .overlay( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
         .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5411764706, green: 
  0.4549019608, blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1)),  
    lineWidth:1)).padding(.horizontal, 50)


          }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Could you prepare standalone reproducible example and screenshot to demo what's wrong?

Comment: I added a screenshot @Asperi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem with the first TextField is that you said `geo.size.width - 100` which would have worked had it not been for the ZStack which gave you that undesired shift.

For the second TextField you had `geo.size.width / 100` which ultimately rendered you with 0 width. You'll find the corrections in code listed below.

For the color, the issue is just your contrast. Instead of using the `.init` for your colors just go with something concrete like `.white` or `.blue` to get you in the ballpark of what you want. Then you should be able to hone in on your desired color from there.

** You'll need to uncomment the comment marks to get your background color back **

Also I adjusted your binding for the textfield, I don't know why you had .text after it.

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var profilSurname = ""
    var body: some View {
        
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                //Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    Text("Picture").font(.system(size: 60)).foregroundColor(.init(red: 45/255, green: 0/255, blue: 112/255))
                    
                    TextField("Adınız", text: $name)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .accentColor(Color.white)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:
                                                    30)
                                    .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5411764706, green: 0.4549019608,
                                                                blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 1)).padding(.horizontal, 50)
                        
                    
                    TextField("Soyadınız", text: $profilSurname)
                        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                        .font(Font.system(size: 30, design: .default))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .accentColor(Color.white)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(Font.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .serif))
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:
                                                    30).stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5411764706, green: 0.4549019608,
                                                                                   blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1)), lineWidth: 1)).padding(.horizontal, 50)
                }
            }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

** ANSWER TO YOUR MOST RECENT QUESTION **

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $third)//-------------->this
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(Font.system(size: 25, design: .default))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .padding(5)
                            .overlay( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .stroke(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5411764706, green:
                     0.4549019608, blue: 0.2823529412, alpha: 1)),
                       lineWidth:1)).padding(.horizontal, 50)
```

Comment: I added your picture, I want a space next to it, as if the sides are sticking out, I don't understand. I want equal space on the left and right. @Sergio Bost

Comment: @metaflor22 Then what you need to do is add .padding() directly after the .overlay modifier, I will edit my answer so you can see

Comment: "Text("iliski")" I added a text below it. Can you fix this too? I tried to do it but it gets bigger and smaller with the text inside. @Sergio Bost

Comment: Just posted the code, in order for that to work you'll need to add a `@State private var third = ""`

Comment: no, you misunderstood me. I don't want to use textfield. I want to use it as text but the stroke appearance will be the same. @Sergio Bost

Comment: I added data on the action page, when the data is selected the text will change but the edges should not be narrowed. @Sergio Bost